# Azure Functions runtime v2.0 Queue MaxPollingInterval ignored

Tags: function, azure

According to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) setting

"queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": 2000,

in host.json will ensure that you don't wait for more than 2 seconds to receive your message.

Property    Default Description
maxPollingInterval  60000   The maximum interval in milliseconds between queue polls.

This does not take effect in the v2 runtime

Answer (score 2):

After debugging the webjobs SDK, it turns out that maxPollingInterval should be defined in a time format.  e.g.

{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:20",
      "maxDequeueCount": 11
    }
  }
}

Will give you 20 seconds max dequeue time